# SessionInformation is null when setting bean of type OAuth2AuthorizationService

Tags: spring, spring-authorization-server

i'm setting up a Spring Authorization server (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server:3.1.2) following the [getting starter guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#defining-required-components) but when setting a bean of `OAuth2AuthorizationService` like so

```
  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
      RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations,
        registeredClientRepository);
  }
```

the id_token is missing the SessionId claim "sid" and therefore the server trowhs an error because it cannot find the claim when using the refresh token to get a new token

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value cannot be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:204) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimsSet$Builder.claim(JwtClaimsSet.java:167) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator.generate(DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator.java:59) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
```

meanwhile if i remove the bean the token "sid" is correctly set

i'm using the JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService to store the autorizations in the database to be able to horizontaly scaling the Authorization server.

am i missing something? sorry i'm tring to learn the Spring Authorization server.

kind regards,
Luca.

Answer (score 0):

Ah silly me,
i forgot to set a SecurityFilterChain for the `/api/**` route, otherwise the security server dont look for a JWT token, [here](https://gist.github.com/SoKnight/397ee1928b121c72c9d2dd254e153232) is the solution i needed to setup a Bean of type SecurityFilterChain with Order 2 with a requestMatcher for the path `/api/**` with

```
       .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
```

since i dont use opaque token like the solution i found

so here is the complete authorization server config

```
package com.lucafaggion.thesis.config;

import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.jackson2.SecurityJackson2Modules;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.JdbcRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.jackson2.OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
// import com.lucafaggion.thesis.common.model.CustomUserDetails;
// import com.lucafaggion.thesis.mixin.CustomUserDetailMixin;
import com.lucafaggion.thesis.model.CustomUserDetails;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthServerConfig {

  @Bean
  public JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
    // RegisteredClient registeredClient =
    // RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    // .clientId("client")
    // .clientSecret("secret")
    // .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
    // .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
    // .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
    // .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
    // .redirectUri("https://oidcdebugger.com/debug")
    // .redirectUri("https://oauthdebugger.com/debug")
    // .redirectUri("https://springone.io/authorized")
    // .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
    // .scope("read")
    // .build();
    // JdbcRegisteredClientRepository repo = new
    // JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcOperations);
    // repo.save(registeredClient);
    return new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcOperations);
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain asSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
        .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults()); // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
    http
        // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
        // authorization endpoint
        .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)));

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2) // add a new filter chain specially for resource server endpoints
  public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .securityMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
        .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(3)
  public SecurityFilterChain appSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }

  // No need for this bean we use a custom user detail service
  // @Bean
  // public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(DataSource dataSource) {
  // JdbcUserDetailsManager manager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
  // return manager;
  // }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
      RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations,
        registeredClientRepository);
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService(
      JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
      RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(jdbcOperations,
        registeredClientRepository);
  }

  @Bean
  public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
    RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
    JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet((JWK) rsaKey);
    return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
  }

  private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
    KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
        .privateKey(privateKey)
        .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .build();
  }

  private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
    KeyPair keyPair;
    try {
      KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
      keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
    return keyPair;
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
    return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! I'm not sure I would have ever spotted that your use case requires a third filter chain. Perhaps you might update the question to add details so that your answer makes sense in context?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg yeah you are right, they key here is that i was using my endpoint from postman and setting the authorization header with the token but the request from postman always returned a login page html and not an actual json response (like the token was ignored), so setting up a third security chain was necessary to make the authetication server act like a resource server for serving REST request, like i wrote on the answer. maybe i should change the title. do you have suggestions?